# WSO2 API Manager deployment on Stratos

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-stratos

Can the API Manager be deployed on Stratos? Where is a how-to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the WSO2 Private PAAS 4.0.0 release you can use the WSO2 api manager with Stratos.

Please find the quick start guide.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/PP400/Quick+Start+Guide

Once you are running the boot.sh to setup WSO2 Private PAAS , it is asking whether you want to deploy APIM (API Manager) service. Then you can enter the 'Y' and proceed with the WS02 api manager deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Currently API Manager is not supported as a cloud service. However, API Manager will be available as a cloud service in the future.

Comment: thanks for the response. I understand it is not bundled with Stratos, but it really cant be deployed on Stratos like some other app?