# WSO2 Stratos Live Services / APIs

Tags: wso2, paas, wso2-stratos

currently I´m evaluating WSO2 Stratos **LIVE** as a public PaaS. I did much research but there are still some questions:

- 1.) Does WSO2 Stratos Live offer a "multi-tenancy-api" to make Java web applications multi-tenant-aware (something like the Google App Engine Namespace API)?
- 2.) Is the cartridge-based architecture available (like in WSO2 Stratos 2)?
- 3.) Are there official API documentations / code samples for all the cloud services? I just found blog posts and webinars. But an official api documentation and code samples would be very great (for example how to unse Identity Server for authentication in Java web applications).
- 4.) Based on [WSO2 API Manager deployment on Stratos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292674/wso2-api-manager-deployment-on-stratos), I assume that the API manager is not available as cloud-service?
- 5.) Do I have hosting options on Stratos Live (e.g. Java Version, the country / Data Center where my app will be hosted)?
- 6.) Does exist a logs-api to access application logs from my application?
- 7.) Are there apis for data handling (for example Map Reduce, execution of cron jobs, CDN)?
- 8.) Do I have a local test environment? I know that there are IDE plugins for an easy deployment. But is it possible to test my app with all WSO2 Stratos Live cloud services local on my machine without connecting to the real services?

I know this is a lot but it would be more than helpful if the WSO2 professionals would help me to answer those questions. As I said, I did much research but those 8 questions are still open.

Thanks a lot and best regards
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the answers in-line.

```
1.) Does WSO2 Stratos Live offer a "multi-tenancy-api" to make Java web applications multi-tenant-aware (something like the Google App Engine Namespace API)?
```

Yes. Your web app can be multi-tenanted.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lEwm6VzAmo&noredirect=1
http://www.slideshare.net/afkham_azeez/building-a-multitenanted-cloudnative-appserver

```
2.) Is the cartridge-based architecture available (like in WSO2 Stratos 2)?
```

Not yet. But our plan is to make Stratos2.0 as the foundation of StratosLive. This will be done after the GA release of Stratos2.0 (it is now in beta stage)

```
3.) Are there official API documentations / code samples for all the cloud services? I just found blog posts and webinars. But an official api documentation and code samples would be very great (for example how to unse Identity Server for authentication in Java web applications).
```

All the documents and samples available for WSO2 products are valid for StratosLive. Reason is, we have deployed the very same product in the cloud. We are in the process of filling the documentation gap with regards to StratosLive at the moment.

```
4.) Based on WSO2 API Manager deployment on Stratos, I assume that the API manager is not available as cloud-service?
```

Not yet. It will be available in the future.

```
5.) Do I have hosting options on Stratos Live (e.g. Java Version, the country / Data Center where my app will be hosted)?
```

No. StratosLive uses shared instances to achieve multi-tenantcy (not like some other PaaSes which uses a JVM per tenant). Therefore, hosting options are not available.

```
6.) Does exist a logs-api to access application logs from my application?
```

Yes. We allow the tenants to view system logs and application logs. Unfortunately the API for log viewing is not documented yet.
http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.com/2012/09/how-distributed-logging-works-in-wso2.html

```
7.) Are there apis for data handling (for example Map Reduce, execution of cron jobs, CDN)?
```

Map reduce related tasks can be handled using toolboxes which can be deployed in WSO2 BAM (monitor.stratoslive.wso2.com). Please check the WSO2 BAM2 documentation for more info.

```
8.) Do I have a local test environment? I know that there are IDE plugins for an easy deployment. But is it possible to test my app with all WSO2 Stratos Live cloud services local on my machine without connecting to the real services?
```

You can download and use the Stratos local setup which can be found at http://wso2.com/cloud/stratos

Comment: How we develop paas application on wso2 cloud?.and why we need apache stratos for that?.can you help me to create simple pass application on wso2 cloud using stratos?.I,m new to opensource cloud